# What is the coefficient of a6b6 in (a+b)12

Tags: combinatorics

I can't use binomial theorem, how should I solve it?

Comment: use [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: You have $21$ terms and have to choose $x$ from $7$ of them, $y$ from $9$ of them and $z$ from the rest of them. How many ways can you do that? (This is essentially the derivation of the multinomial theorem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the $21$ factors of $(x+y+z)^{21}$, you have to choose $7$ that you pick the $x$ from, and from the remaining $14$ factors, you have to choose $9$ to pick an $y$ from. From the remaining $5$ factors you will pick the $z$. The total number of summands is:
$$
\binom{21}{7}\cdot\binom{14}{9}\cdot\binom{5}{5}=\frac{21!}{7!\cdot9!\cdot5!}=\binom{21}{7, 9, 5}
$$